# Button Disable on press tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, atom-editor

I'm making a mining game and whenever a user clicks 'mine' button, I want it to disable so the user cant click it again until cool down wears off. I made a sample of the code, I state the definition first, then make the button, but since the button is after, the def doesn't know what variable the 'mine' button is. Any help appreciated!

````
root = Tk()


def def1():
    btn[state] = 'disabled'

Btn = Button(root, text="button", command= def1())



root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: The command should be `def1` not `def1()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


def enable_btn():
    btn.config(state="normal")

def def1():
    print("Clicked")
    btn.config(state="disabled")
    # 1000 is the cooldown in ms (so 1000 = 1 sec)
    btn.after(1000, enable_btn)

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text="button", command=def1)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I am using a `.after` script so the `enable_btn` function runs 1 sec after `def1` is called.